# Getting projectiles to move relevant to time SFML C++

Tags: c++, time, sfml

I need to get my projectiles moving relevant to time. As well as sprite animation.

The code that I have for my bullets at the moment is as follows. They do not seem to animate with relevance to time. To be honest I am pretty baffled by this.

```
struct BulletData
{
    sf::Vector2f direction; 
    sf::Vector2f startpos;  
    float        speed;     
    bool         active;    
    BulletData()
    {
        direction = sf::Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f);
        startpos = sf::Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f);
        speed    = 600000.0f;
        active   = false;
    }
};
        sf::Time        dt; // delta time
    sf::Time        elapsedTime;

    sf::Clock clock;

    elapsedTime += dt;
    int timeAsMs = elapsedTime.asMilliseconds(); 
        dt = clock.restart();


 void Game::updateBulletCollisions(sf::Time dt)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < NO_BULLETS; i++)
    {
        if (this->_arr_bullet_data[i].active)
        {
            sf::Vector2f tbulletvel = this->_arr_bullet_data[i].direction * this->_arr_bullet_data[i].speed * dt.asSeconds();
            this->_arr_bullet_spr[i].move(tbulletvel);
       }
}
```

Regards
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show `updateBulletCollisions` being called, my guess is that `sf::Time dt` is a delta, i.e. time elapsed since last call.

If your `updateBulletCollisions` function is called at a constant rate (50 hertz for example), the results of your calculation that sets `tbulletvel` will always give you the same value.

Instead, you would want something like `_arr_bullet_spr[i].move(_arr_bullet_spr[i].pos + tbulletvel)`, or pass in an absolute time (like your `sf::Time elapsedTime`) instead of a delta.